# Taylor series of function

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I need to find the Taylor series of $f(x)=x^2c^x$ centered at $x_0=0$. I tried to take the first three derivatives to look for a pattern, but apparently, this is not the best way, the derivatives started getting pretty hairy.

Is there any other way of doing this without expecting "magical patterns" on the derivatives such as in $f(x)=e^x$ and $f(x)=\sin x$?

Comment: Try expanding $c^x$ and then just multiplying through by $x^2$.

Comment: @Bye_World Such avoidance of product rule techniques...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get for the series: 
$$x^2c^x\simeq x^2+\ln(c)x^3+\dfrac{1}{2}\ln(c)^2x^4+...$$
so you have:
$$x^2c^x=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\dfrac{x^{k+2}}{k!}\ln(c)^{k}$$

Comment: @Bye_World: Ok. I agree

Answer (score 2):

You need to find taylor serie of $c^x$  and multiply by x^2.

taylor serie of $c^x$ is $1 + ln(c)x + {1}/{2!} ln(c)^2x^2$ + ..

Answer (score 2):

Just to show you that the derivatives aren't that hairy:

For comfort I'll use $c=e$ but the generalization is straightforward.

$$f(x)=x^2e^x$$
$$f'(x)=2xe^x+x^2e^x$$
$$f''(x)=2e^x+4xe^x+x^2e^x$$
$$f'''(x)=6e^x+6xe^x+x^2e^x$$
$$f'''(x)=12e^x+8xe^x+x^2e^x$$
$$\cdots$$

For all following derivatives, there are just three terms $e^x,xe^x,x^2e^x$. The third one has a unit coefficient, the middle one seems to be $2n$ and the first, the double of a triangular number, $(n-1)n$. (This comes form the recurrence relation between the coefficients.)

Indeed,

$$(((n-1)n+2nx+x^2)e^x)'=(2n+2x+(n-1)n+2nx+x^2)e^x\\
=(n(n+1)+2(n+1)x+x^2)e^x.$$

Then $f^{(n)}(0)=(n-1)n$.

---

The Taylor development is thus

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{(n-1)n}{n!}x^n=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{x^n}{(n-2)!}.$$

---

You can establish that in a more systematic way by means of the generalized formula for the derivatives of a product:

$$(f\cdot g)^{(n)}=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nkf^{(k)}g^{(n-k)}.$$

There are just three nonzero derivatives of $x^2$ and $c^x$ yields $\ln^n(c)c^x$.

Then

$$(x^2c^x)^{(n)}=\binom n22\ln^{n-2}(c)+\binom n12x\ln^{n-1}(c)+\binom n0x^2\ln^n(c)\\
=((n-1)n\ln^{n-2}(c)+2nx\ln^{n-1}(c)+x^2\ln^n(c))c^x.$$

Answer (score 1):

Because $c^x$ has a derivative proportional to $c^x$, where the proportionally constant is known, it will have a nice formula for the $n$ th derivative so find the Taylor series for $c^x$.